# Mutability of Date with getter and setter in java

Tags: java, reference, mutable

Since Dates are mutable in java and their getters setters are preferred directly as

```
public void setDate(Date date){
   this.date = date;
}

public Date getDate(){
   return this.date;
}
```

So I wrote a code on Ideone to verify this,

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    private class Test{
        private Date date;

        public void setDate(Date date){
            this.date = date;
        }

        public Date getDate(){
            return this.date;
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Ideone abc = new Ideone();
        abc.functionTest();

    }

    public void functionTest(){
        Date tempDate = new Date(1403685556000L);
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setDate(tempDate);
        tempDate = new Date(1435221556000L);
        Date abc = test.getDate();
        Long def = abc.getTime();
        System.out.println("Date 1:"+def.toString());
        test.setDate(tempDate);
        def = abc.getTime();
        System.out.println("Date 2:"+def.toString());
    }
}
```

I got the following result as output

```
Date 1:1403685556000
Date 2:1403685556000
```

These are the original Dates and not the changed one. 
This is result is opposed to as expected from Mutability of Date object in java.

why I am getting this unexpected behaviour?

Here is [Ideone Code](http://ideone.com/VRnudJ)

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Yes, why I am getting this unexpected behaviour

Comment: You never changed your `Date`, you just created a new one.

Comment: You're setting a new reference to Date. So, it's logical that you're "original" Date is not changed since it does not point to the new reference.

Comment: But the second time, in line `test.setDate(tempDate)` i referenced tempDate to Test.date, but def is not updated in last System.println

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a new reference to Date with `tempDate = new Date(1435221556000L);` (then `test.setDate(tempDate);`).

So, your "original" Date is not changed since it does not point to the new reference.

```
    Date tempDate = new Date(1403685556000L);    // first reference.
    Test test = new Test();                  
    test.setDate(tempDate);                      
    tempDate = new Date(1435221556000L);         // second reference.
    Date abc = test.getDate();                   // you take the first reference since you do not set "tempDate" in Test before.
    Long def = abc.getTime();
    System.out.println("Date 1:"+def.toString()); // you print the first reference.
    test.setDate(tempDate);                       // you set the second reference and overwrite the first one.
    def = abc.getTime();                          // but "abc" still points on first reference.
    System.out.println("Date 2:"+def.toString());
```

This is pointer: your `abc` variable points on the first instance of `Date` (declared by `new Date(1403685556000L)`). If you change value of `Test.date` by setting a new instance, `abc` will still points on the previous pointer.

**BUT**, if you change the `Test.date` value using `Date` instance methods, you will not change reference of the `Test.date` and your `abc` variable will reflect these changes.

Comment: But the second time, in line test.setDate(tempDate) i referenced tempDate to Test.date, but def is not updated in last System.println

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the second `tempDate` later.